# Can a Society of Barbie Dolls Make a Network of Aerial Cable Cars?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, engineering, transportation

When I was a kid, I conceptualized a post-apocalyptic story entirely starring Barbie dolls. One idea I had about how they would live and get around involved transmission towers, or power towers. Imagine something like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_tower#/media/File%3APylon_ds.jpg). Note: By the time they started living there, the power lines had long since stopped working.

These dolls would be as smart as humans, but can only lift about 5-10 pounds. They're functionally immortal, since only way to kill one is to completely destroy it by setting it ablaze. They eat, drink and sleep to maintain their energy levels and keep their strength up. Not doing it won't kill them, but will make them very tired and weak.

The idea was that somehow they were able to live in different parts of this tower (with branch platforms or nets and hammocks) and get to different floors with stairs or an elevator up the side or down the middle of the tower.

However, the main benefit to living in this power tower that I thought of was to create a system of Gondola lifts or Cable cars to travel from one tower to another with the power tower's wires. Looking back I don't see how I thought that was supposed to work. But that's where you come in!

How could a society of Barbie dolls build and maintain a system of Aerial tramways connecting a bunch of power towers?

Comment: Isn't the real question why?

Comment: As for the why, i had thought that this might be a faster way of going between towers that simply walking on the ground.

Comment: I am open to alternatives, but I didn't want to ask too many questions in one post.

Comment: How are Barbie dolls different from regular humans? Do they have any advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: I had always imagined that they would be as smart as humans, able to lift 5-10 pounds, immune to disease and be functionally immortal unless they're entirely destroyed (I.e completely burned up).

Comment: Please add any constraints you imagine about the dolls to the post by [edit]ing it.

Comment: will do @Secespitus!

Comment: Kinda tough without fingers and elbows.

Comment: What about them being *Barbie dolls* is relevant, as opposed to 10-inch-tall humans?  Is a plastic-like skin relevant?  Absence of elbow and knee joints?  Frozen faces that would seem to preclude speech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cable cars and gondolas tend to use moving cables, although designs with a static cable are possible and some are actually used by Nation Grid for inspection and repair.

But unfortunately the biggest problem is that power cables are connected to pylons by large insulated connectors like this

[image: insulator]

This would make using them as a cableway difficult.

[image: barbie]

But some would still try it...
(she was later rescued)

Comment: It would necessitate a stop and moving to a separate car at each pylon, but otherwise would work.

Comment: That seems like a good place to hang a suspension loading dock. Thanks for the idea!